# Maven download the *.lastupdated files

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

When I try to to install maven project in local repository, I notice that pom and jar files have .lastUpdated extension. Because of this issue I cannot build my project which depends on it.

I tried the following approach, but it was ineffective.

1.mvn -U clean install

2.project -> Maven -> update maven project -> force update of snapshots/Releases

3.Project -> Run as -> Maven clean(Working- build success) &&  Project -> Run as -> Maven install(build failed)

**Maven Version:** Apache Maven 3.8.6

I've created a simple Maven project. I got below error in pom.xml

```
   Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/maven-surefire-common/2.12.4/maven-surefire-common-2.12.4.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.9/maven-reporting-api-2.0.9.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-toolchain/2.0.9/maven-toolchain-2.0.9.pom
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.1/maven-plugin-annotations-3.1.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.413 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-12-08T09:33:19+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project test: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.12.4 -> org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:jar:2.12.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-booter:pom:2.12.4 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-booter/2.12.4/surefire-booter-2.12.4.pom: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message -> [Help 1]
```

Also, I checked that the download files have the.lastupdated extension in the {userpath}.m2\repository path.

Comment: please provide: Maven version, example project , logs of excuting

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski Thanks for your reply. Please look into the updated post.

Comment: Which JDK version exactly you use?

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski java version: "1.8.0_291"

Comment: Try with the last JDK 1.8 version - https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/jdk8u/Main

Comment: What is in your .m2/settings.xml file?